# Bootstrap 3 - Impossible to remove ul vertical spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on Bootstrap 3 (last release) for the first time, and I experience the classic padding/margin headache Bootstrap seems to provide to its newcomers... After many efforts and a while on the web, I declare my defeat and beg your help !

Down here is the simplest way to show my issue, questions being : 
- why is there a difference in text vertical alignment ?
- why do green backgrounds have different heights ?
- how can I align all my babies (texts and backgrounds) ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Problem Tests</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap minimum viewport -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <style>
    /* --- Rebooting all margins and paddings --- */
    .container-fluid, .row, [class*="col-"], h1, ul, li, nav, div {
      margin: 0px;
      padding : 0px;
    }

    h1, li {
      background-color: green;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
  </style>
    
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div id="left" class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="col-xs-12">TEST TITLE</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right" class="col-xs-9">
        <nav class="row">
          <ul>
            <li class="col-xs-12">TEST LINK</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I thought overriding all bootstrap margins and padding would do the trick, but... nah... Plz help and thx for reading ! Hope the question is not too stupid (last time I made a website was yeeeears ago !)

Comment: Warm thanks to all of you for answering in less than 5 minutes ! I was unaware of line-height mechanics, beginner's lack of knowledge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both have different line-heights

The `h1` has a line-height of 22px while the `li` has a line-height of 28.57714302062988px

If you make the line-heights match everything will line up.

```
h1, li {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

Comment: change `h1` to `li` and it fix the issue, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ytL6r423/ or change the `li` to `h1` which ever suits (don't wana post my answer) :)

Comment: @Shehary I think you left a comment on an answer instead of comment on the question? If that's the case please consider moving your comment to the question. Otherwise the context is all weird, lol.

Comment: @hungerstar don't wana post the answer so adding the fiddle here to above answer

Comment: @Shehary that's pure silliness. You're just going to confuse people. Gotta love the internet.

Comment: @hungerstar i have my fill of the day :D even i upvoted this answer :)

Comment: @Shehary Semantically you may want to retain an `h1` and an `li` so changing both to `li` may not be wanted. In which case using CSS to match the line-height would be best.

Comment: @Jrod you are right, you can edit the fiddle and add it in your answer. http://jsfiddle.net/ytL6r423/

Comment: @all : since you're all helping me, I don't mind anyone confusing the page xD. Last question : line-height defines the height of a text line, so if font-size is 20px and line-height is 22px, does it mean 1px top spacing and 1px bottom spacing ?

Comment: @KLôN yes, the extra would be averaged out. The text will be in the middle of the line-height. `line-height` is often used to vertically align text in horizontal navigation menus.

Comment: @hungerstar : warm thanks, solves many situations, I wonder how I could have missed that...

Answer (score 1):

They have different line-heights.

The `h1` has a `line-height` of `1.1` which will be 1.1 x `font-size`.

The `li` has a `line-height` of `1.42857143` which will be 1.42857143 x `font-size`.

Comment: @Shehary lol, you too funny. If you'd posted an answer I could've up-voted you! :)

Comment: was just trying to have some fun and i would have posted the answer but 2 senior and high reputed users posted an answers and also my answer was wrong so i thought better to sit back and learn from seniors.

Answer (score 0):

In you css rebooting you should add `line-height` property which related to align your text vertical alignment.

```css
.container-fluid, .row, [class*="col-"], h1, ul, li, nav, div {
      margin: 0px;
      padding : 0px;
      line-height: 24px;
    }

    h1, li {
      background-color: green;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div id="left" class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="col-sm-12">TEST TITLE</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right" class="col-sm-9">
        <nav class="row">
          <ul>
            <li class="header_sm_text col-sm-12">TEST LINK</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having does not have anything to do with margin or padding. In fact that both h1 and li elements have text inside of them, they both have a line-height property set and in this case their values are different.